# Images in web notifications, Opera 25+

Tags: notifications, opera-extension

Has anyone found out how to show images in Opera 25+ web notifications yet?

According to Opera, it should be possible, but I can't find any reference to how it's done. Already tried using it through the Chrome notifications API which is (partially) supported, with no luck. Should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "O" icon on the left or the "batman" on the right?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. The current implementation is on the same level as the W3C web notifications. You can only create simple message with icon attached. It is not possible to attach any additional image.

Comment: So the screenshot by Opera is literally not possible yet? It's just a tease? https://dev.opera.com/blog/web-notifications-in-opera-developer-24/

Comment: I don't expect intentional acting of the author. It might be based on some internal build that has not been eventually released. The article definitely needs fixing since it's misleading.